# Return to the Original Text by Traversing Huffman Tree in Python

Tags: python-3.x, huffman-code

I am trying to use Huffman in my program. I am using this code [here](https://github.com/nicktimko/huffman/blob/master/huffman/huffman.py) to generate codes from input text. 
I used it as they explained, for example:

```
message='man the stand banana man'    
huffman.codebook(collections.Counter(message).items())
```

this will generate a tree for the text and assign code to each character. the tree presented as `dict`.

```
huffTree= {'m': '0111', 'a': '10', 'n': '00', ' ': '111', 't': '1101', 'h': '0101', 'e': '0100', 's': '0110', 'd': '11001', 'b': '11000'}
```

I applied this to generate the bit-stream:

```
bitStream = []
for ch in message:
     bitStream.append(huffTree[ch])
```

then the bit-stream generated from the sentence is: `011110001111101010101001110110110110001100111111000100010001011101111000`

what I want now is how to return the bit-stream generated to the original text by traversing the tree in python. I was trying a lot to solve this but with no avail and there was no clear solution for this step.

Comment: Code or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that Huffman codes are [prefix code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) we can take advantage of this to decode your bit stream:

```
# Create a lookup map
lookup = { v:k for k,v in huffTree.items()}

# The decode function
def huffman_decode(msg):                   
 left = 0
 decoded = ''
 for right in range(len(msg)+1):
     token = msg[left:right]
     if token in lookup:
         decoded += lookup[token]
         left = right
 return decoded

 huffman_decode(bitStream) #'man the stand banana man'
```